# display a desired tab upon clicking a link

Tags: php, jquery

I have a facebook bubble notification. If the user would click the View All messages, the messages tab should be opened. How can I achieve this?

this is what I've tried:

```
<script>
$('.view_applications').click(function(){
$( "#tabs" ).tabs("select", "#tabs-5" );
return true;
});</script>


<div class="bbbbbbb" id="view<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <div style="background-color: #F7F7F7; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; position: relative; z-index: 100; padding:8px; cursor:pointer;">
                <a href="#" class="view_applications" id="<?php    echo $id; ?>">View all <?php echo $comment_count; ?> application/s</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But it's not displaying the desired tab. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by : "it's not displaying the desired tab."  It seems from your code that the click event is not triggered at all

Comment: You should put your code within document ready handler.

Comment: Why does your click handler `return true`?

Comment: the tab 5 should be displayed upon clicking.

Comment: @undefined please give me an example to do it. Newbie to jquery thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initalized the DOM ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   // do your work here



        $('.view_applications').click(function(){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs("select", "#tabs-5" );
          return false;
         });



});
```

EDIT :

First initialize your tabs when document is ready :

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

then select your desired tab :

```
$('.view_applications').click(function(){
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs("select", "#tabs-5" );
  return false;
});
```

-----see the `return false;` ----------

Comment: yes I forgot to initialize. After doing so, still it isn't displaying the tab 5

Comment: is their any DIV in your html with ID as 'tabs-5'

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes have you included the jquery before this script?

Comment: @MohammadAdil yes I have tabs-5 div